# Adding objects to an existing array of objects - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, dynamic-arrays

I've created an array of 2 objects, and I wish to write an 'add' function to dynamically add more people to this array.

Can you explain why the 'add' function below does not add an object to the 'contacts' array successfully.

```
var bob = {
    firstName: "Bob",
    lastName: "Jones",
    phoneNumber: "(650) 777-7777",
    email: "bob.jones@example.com"
};

var mary = {
    firstName: "Mary",
    lastName: "Johnson",
    phoneNumber: "(650) 888-8888",
    email: "mary.johnson@example.com"
};

var contacts = [bob, mary];
var contactsLength = contacts.length;

function add (firstName, lastName, phoneNumber, email) {
    contacts[contactsLength] = {
        firstName: firstName,
        lastName: lastName,
        phoneNumber: phoneNumber,
        email: email
    };
};


function printPerson(person) {
    console.log(person.firstName + " " + person.lastName);
}

function list() {
    for (var i = 0; i < contactsLength; i++) {
        printPerson(contacts[i]);
    }
}

add("MJ", "Foster", "MJ@gmail", "714-333-5555");

list();
```

Comment: Dont forget to increase the contactsLength var.. You add but dont list the extra one because you did not add one to the count.

Comment: it does. have a look better on your printPerson function and the for loop. try to change it to "var i = 0; i <= contactsLength; i++) if you can see the error ...

Answer (score 2):

The reason your code isn't working the way you think it should is because of this line:

```
var contactsLength = contacts.length;
```

Here, you're assigning the value of `contacts.length` to the variable `contactsLength`, but thereafter, `contactsLength` will not change even if the size of your `contacts` array changes.

Instead, you should simply refer to the property `contacts.length`.

Here is a corrected version of your code:

```
var bob = {
    firstName: "Bob",
    lastName: "Jones",
    phoneNumber: "(650) 777-7777",
    email: "bob.jones@example.com"
};

var mary = {
    firstName: "Mary",
    lastName: "Johnson",
    phoneNumber: "(650) 888-8888",
    email: "mary.johnson@example.com"
};

var contacts = [bob, mary];

function add (firstName, lastName, phoneNumber, email) {
    contacts[contacts.length] = {
        firstName: firstName,
        lastName: lastName,
        phoneNumber: phoneNumber,
        email: email
    };
};


function printPerson(person) {
    console.log(person.firstName + " " + person.lastName);
}

function list() {
    for (var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
        printPerson(contacts[i]);
    }
}

add("MJ", "Foster", "MJ@gmail", "714-333-5555");

list();
```

Please note: using the native array method `push()`, would do exactly the same same thing as `contacts[contacts.length] = {...}`.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use push method

```
 function add (firstName, lastName,  phoneNumber, email) { 
var newContact = { 
    firstName: firstName, 
    lastName: lastName, 
    phoneNumber: phoneNumber, 
    email: email 
    }; 
    contacts.push(newContact);
 };
```

Comment: Thanks, great suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

Your **Add** function works fine, although a better way would be to use a *push()* method as per @MysterX as keeping a track of array index might not 
always prove very reliable especially if you are using public variable for tracking it. [*push()*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) method

Your error is in your **printPerson** function. Have a closer look on your *for* loop and change it a bit into this

```
function list() {
    for (var i = 0; i <= contactsLength; i++) {
        printPerson(contacts[i]);
    }
}
```

and see if you can spot the error...

Hope this helps.